# Creating a MySQL multilingual dictionary table that expands horizontally adding/removing columns

Tags: mysql, dictionary

The goal is to create a **multilingual dictionary MySQL table of words** that use a key => value structure for any desired language. Current solutions (and threads) on stackoverflow refer to adding new key => values pairs as **rows** to an existing table.

The problem is synchronizing keys for every available language. My application uses placeholders %{example} that refer to a specific key in a dictionary. When users switch to a different language that placeholder needs to be present in the dictionary.

Proposed solution:

Rather than adding a key => value pair per language as row, add a column per language and use every row as a unique key.

| key (pk) | en_EN | se_SE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | apple | apple |
| fish | fish | fisk |

Now we add a new language **nl_NL** as column, automatically creating every required key with value NULL.

| key (pk) | en_EN | se_SE | nl_NL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | apple | apple | NULL |
| fish | fish | fisk | NULL |

Retrieving the entire dictionary for a specific language would be as easy as:

```
SELECT en_EN FROM <table>
```

Since this approach feels a bit unusual namely dynamically adding/removing columns as opposed to rows, I was wondering if I'm missing something or if there is a better approach. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much better approach using joins.

Create one table "terms" with the all the keys/terms and then another table "translations" with the term, locale and translation.

To get all english translation use

```
select term, translation
  from terms
  join translations using (term)
 where locale = "en_US"
```

You can use a left join to find the null elements if you need to.

Comment: Nice! This looks way better than my approach which requires meddling with the table structure. Thanks a lot!